# Help powering an old heater control board im trying to reprogram

Tags: power-supply, batteries, uart

[image: Amana-RSKP0009 board]
Not photo of my specific board.

I got 3 old universal controller board's , I'm attempting to reprogram them to learn hardware hacking. But i not quiet sure what would be the best method of powering it.

It says on the board that it uses a 24VAC transformer.  But the minimum is a "12VA class 2 only".  I'm wondering if it would be a safer to wire batteries together to power it, and if i can go under 12 volts. I'm not going to be using the massive relays so i shouldn't need the full amount of power?

Board name: Amana rskp0009

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Your questions are a confusing mix, so would you please clean up your text and ask specific questions. "I'm wondering" is not a question but puzzlement on your part.

Comment: Why do you want to reprogram it?

Comment: Im getting into hardware hacking and i figured this would be an easy start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it has a switching supply to reduce the 30VDC+ from the 24VAC transformer to whatever the coil voltage is on the relays (12V?), and then another stage to reduce it to the power supply (5V?) for the MCU.

The easiest thing is to just get a common 24VAC transformer.

Comment: OK thank you i will look for them on amazon. For beginners is it safe to plug with directly in a wall? or would you recommend finding a safer way?

Comment: The 24VAC transformer should provide isolation and contact with 24VAC is not particularly dangerous (provided you're not  doing something really silly like puncturing your skin or standing in a pail of salt water), so I would say the main danger is to the board-and possibly connected things like a computer. Carefully insulate the mains terminals on the transformer if they are otherwise exposed. Keep your setup cleanly organized and avoid setting the board on anything metallic. By the way, "Class 2" means that you can short the transformer without a *safety* issue, but don't do it deliberately.

Comment: Before i buy. would this be sufficient? https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0007N72TC/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A278TE67X5QD13

Comment: @GameHog It looks okay. I'd spend a couple extra dollars for the TRG2440 since it has a resettable fuse inside.

Answer (score 1):

> It says on the board that it uses a 24VAC transformer. But the minimum is a "12VA ..."

This part of transformer specification means that it should be a 24 V transformer capable of at least 12 VA.

$$ A = \frac {VA}{V} = \frac {12}{24} = 0.5~A $$

The transformer should be rated > 12 VA or > 0.5 A at 24 V.

Comment: OK thank you. and there is no way of having any lower voltages I'm assuming. I only need to processor to run a program i write. The relays will not be wired to anything else. So the extra voltage wont be needed.

Comment: It looks like the power supply is on the bottom left corner of the board. (White connector, master switch, big capacitors, some kind of inductor brick? and a largish transistor or bridge rectifier. The three capacitors suggest that there are three different DC voltages used. This would make it tricky to power other than by the transformer.